# Plotting triangles based on a single point with distance and angle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, education

I'm tasked with creating an arrowhead within a pdf program.

I have a single point with at $x=5.6$, $y=4$ this would be point A of my triangle I want to make the  sides equal at $90$ degrees angles and a distance of around $.1$. How would I go about doing this, or is this even possible? Im pretty rusty on trig.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use vectors or complex numbers.
In this case,
they are essentially the same.

If a point is at
$(x, y)$,
to rotate it
about the origin
by an angle $t$,
do a multiplication
(switching between
points and complex numbers)

$\begin{array}\\
(x+iy)e^{it}
&= (x+iy)(\cos t+i \sin t)\\
&=(x, y)(\cos t, \sin t)\\
&=(x\cos t-y\sin t)+i(x\sin t+y \cos t)\\
&=(x\cos t-y\sin t, x\sin t+y \cos t)\\
\end{array}
$

This is all standard stuff
which you will 
have to get familiar with
to do the things you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, would there be any way you could provide an example, I can stare at this all day but if i dont see actual numbers I won't understand it.